# Android Banner display at bottom overlap scrollview

Tags: android, banner-ads, adbannerview

I have a scrollview and a banner at the bottom of screen. It seems the banner wil overlap the scrollview of content when orientation is landscape. May be it will overlap too if the screen size is smaller as I am testing in Samsung S3.

Is it wrong ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/large_photo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@+id/LargePhoto"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/sample" />

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:baselineAligned="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp" >

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/idReference_no_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="參考編號"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/idReference_no_details"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idReference_no_title"
                            android:text="A1234"
                            android:textColor="#0000FF"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/idHints"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/promotion_details"
                            android:text="【按圖顯示】"
                            android:textColor="#FF3300"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/promotion_details"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show_map_details"
                            android:contentDescription="@+id/hasPromotion_details"
                            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                            android:paddingRight="2dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/promotion" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/show_map_details"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show_street"
                            android:contentDescription="@+id/show_map_details_name"
                            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                            android:paddingRight="2dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/googlemap" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/show_street"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@+id/show_street_desc"
                            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/street" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
>



                    <LinearLayout
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:baselineAligned="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="詳細地址"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/HouseMall_Address_details"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="AAAAAA"
                            android:textColor="#0000FF"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:baselineAligned="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="室內／外"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/indoor_or_outdoor_details"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@+id/indoor_outdoor_details_name"
                            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                            android:paddingRight="2dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/indoor_18x18" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="提供泊車種類"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="時租"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="日泊"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="夜泊"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="全日泊"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="收費 星期一至五"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/Hour_MonToFri"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="$18"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/Day_MonToFri"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="$60"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/Night_MonToFri"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="$60"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/W24_MonToFri"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="$60"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="星期六日及假期"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/Hour_SatToSun"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="$60"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/Day_SatToSun"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="$60"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/Night_SatToSun"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="$60"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                        <TextView
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/W24_SatToSun"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:text="$60"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" >

                    <TextView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="月租"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/Monthly_Fee"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="$2400"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
                </TableLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp" >

                    <TextView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="付款方法"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/paid_octopus_details"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@+id/paid_octopus_desc_details"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingRight="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/octopus" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/paid_visa_details"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@+id/paid_visa_desc_details"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingRight="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/visa" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/paid_cash_details"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@+id/paid_cash_desc_details"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingRight="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/cash" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="其他設施"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/charger_details"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@+id/charger_desc_details"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingRight="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/recharge" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/wash_details"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@+id/wash_desc_details"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingRight="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/carwash" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cctv_details"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@+id/cctv_desc_details"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:paddingRight="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/cctv" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/page_ad_specificregion_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/page_ad_sample" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `Banner-ImageView` "before" the `ScrollView` and add the following line to your `ScrollView`

```
android:layout_above="@id/page_ad_specificregion_details"
```

Comment: Pretty unlikely that this crash is related to the code above. Could please tell us what the Error is?

Answer (score 0):

please try this if getting problem then replay otherwise give +1.

change last imageview with this code.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/page_ad_specificregion_details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" />
```